# How to use push notifications on Corona for Android?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, coronasdk

I am learning to use the corona SDK,
I want to send push notifications through GCM or Firebase on my app.
I followed the guidelines mentioned [here](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/events/appNotification/index.html), but I am still not able to send notifications on the android app

Comment: Try be more specific. Also describe your problem in detail. Now it is hard for me to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that question belongs to the [Coronalabs forums](https://forums.coronalabs.com/) as corona sdk is a proprietary software. However, you can try [One Signal Firebase plugin for Corona](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/corona-sdk) as their documentations supports Firebase integration with Corona SDK.